# How do you create a matrix from a text file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I have a text file which has 4 columns, each column having 65536 data points. Every element in the row is separated by a comma. For example:

```
X,Y,Z,AU
4010.0,3210.0,-440.0,0.0
4010.0,3210.0,-420.0,0.0
etc.
```

So, I have **65536** rows, each row having 4 data values as shown above. I want to convert it into a matrix. I tried importing data from the text file to an excel file, because that way its easy to create a matrix, but I lost more than half the data.

Answer (score 24):

If all the entries in your file are numeric, you can simply use `a = load('file.txt')`.  It should create a 65536x4 matrix `a`.  It is even easier than `csvread`

Comment: And what about if the entries are integers, floats, and strings?

Answer (score 9):

Have you ever tried using 'importdata'?
The parameters you need only file name and delimiter.

```
>> tmp_data = importdata('your_file.txt',',')

tmp_data = 

          data: [2x4 double]
      textdata: {'X'  'Y'  'Z'  'AU'}
    colheaders: {'X'  'Y'  'Z'  'AU'}


>> tmp_data.data

ans =

        4010        3210        -440           0
        4010        3210        -420           0

>> tmp_data.textdata

ans = 

    'X'    'Y'    'Z'    'AU'
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of messing with Excel, you should be able to read the text file directly into MATLAB (using the functions [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html), [FGETL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fgetl.html), [FSCANF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html), and [FCLOSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fclose.html)):

```
fid = fopen('file.dat','rt');  %# Open the data file
headerChars = fgetl(fid);      %# Read the first line of characters
data = fscanf(fid,'%f,%f,%f,%f',[4 inf]).';  %'# Read the data into a
                                              %# 65536-by-4 matrix
fclose(fid);  %# Close the data file
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do it would be to use MATLAB's [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html) function.

There is also [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6012) tool which reads CSV files.

You could do it yourself without too much difficulty either: Just loop over each line in the file and split it on commas and put it in your array.

Answer (score 5):

Suggest you familiarize yourself with [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html) and [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html).

`dlmread` is like `csvread` but because it can handle any delimiter (tab, space, etc), I tend to use it rather than `csvread`.

`textscan` is the real workhorse: lots of options, + it works on open files and is a little more robust to handling "bad" input (e.g. non-numeric data in the file). It can be used like `fscanf` in gnovice's suggestion, but I think it is faster (don't quote me on that though).

Comment: **[dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)** works very good, thanks. However since it only works with numeric data, I had to enumerate small number of strings in my data. Other options should be considered when it's not convenient to do so.

Comment: uh.... as I said in my post 4 years ago: `textscan` is the real workhorse: lots of options, + it works on open files and is a little more robust to handling "bad" input (e.g. non-numeric data in the file)