# How to make value in excel sheet become element of matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, matrix, datasheet

i have xls file name `databus.xls`, like this

```
No. Bus Code    Voltage Mag.    Fasa    Beban       Generator       Stat Mvar       
                MW  Mvar    MW  Mvar    Qmin    Qmax    +Qc/-Ql'
1   1   1.04    0   50  30.99   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   170 105.35  0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   200 123.94  0   0   0   0   20
4   2   1.02    0   80  49.58   318 0   0   0   0
```

how to make the value become component of matrix a

like

```
a=[1  1   1.04 0 50 30.99 ...etc
   2  0   1    0  170 105.35 ...etc
   ...etc                           ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one time operation, copy-paste is the simplest approach. If not, I would suggest [`xlsread`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)

Try:

```
filename = 'databus.xls';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'A3:J7';

a = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange)
```

If there's only one sheet, you can skip the second argument and just do:

```
filename = 'databus.xls';
a = xlsread(filename,'A3:J7')
```

If you do not know the range, simply follow the documentation given in the link above:

> num = xlsread(filename) reads data from the first worksheet in the
>   Microsoft® Excel® spreadsheet file named filename and returns the
>   numeric data in array num.

So, to show an example:

[image]

```
num = xlsread('test.xlsx')
num =
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   50.0000   30.0000
    2.0000    1.0000    1.0000  112.0000   60.0000
    3.0000    2.0000    4.0000   40.0000   20.0000
    4.0000    2.0000    3.0000   30.0000   20.0000
    5.0000    3.0000    2.0000   60.0000   42.5000
```

As this reads all numeric data, you might get some rows with mostly NANs, if only a few of the columns contain numbers. If that's the case, you can simply delete those lines.

Comment: what if the xlrange have customable range? the xls data wasnt fixed and editable

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your task in two:

1. Export your data from Excel.
2. Import your data into Matlab.

For task 2, there are several options (links to official documentation are provided):

1. [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)
2. [dimread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)
3. [fscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)
4. [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)
5. Etc.?

See also [Ways to Import Text Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html) and [How do you create a matrix from a text file in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016277/how-do-you-create-a-matrix-from-a-text-file-in-matlab).

If you use method 1 for task 2, then you have to export as csv from Excel.

1. Copy your worksheet into a new one.
2. Remove data not going into your matrix (as per your question, the first two rows).
3. Save as CSV.

Voilà